# Can a dependent voltage/current source have some impedence/admittance,respectively?

Tags: circuit-analysis, network

Im studying 2-port networks, for Z parameters equations, there is general equivalent circuit given, in which dependent voltage source is given, I do know about dependent voltage sources, but do these sources have some impedence? i.e Vx = Z*I, where Vx is a dependent source ?

In image, red highlighted circuit;
 "circuit[image: circuit image]"

Comment: Never mind -- I just turned this into my answer.

Comment: Yes they can. That's exactly what they're showing in your example with the symbols labelled \$Z_{11}\$ and \$Z_{22}\$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you're dealing with circuit theory like that, a dependent source is a pure voltage source with zero impedance, or a pure current source with zero admittance. (Unless the author is marching to their own drummer). If you want to indicate a dependent source with an impedance you do what they did there and indicate it as a separate circuit element.